# Excel chart returning too many ranges (sometimes)

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**: I have a workbook with several worksheets each with the same structure.  Each worksheet has several sets of columns all of the same structure.  Each set of columns 4 columns containing a heading and 100+ rows of data (always the same number of rows for all columns).

**Goal**: I need to produce a line chart for every set of columns on every sheet.

**Macro**: One subroutine creates a chart for a single set of rows.  A calling routine sets the top left corner, calls the chart routine and then moves 7 columns to the right until that cell is empty.  The outer routine clears all charts on a sheet and then calls this repeatedly for each sheet.

**Problem**: Macro is tested and working on test workbook with 2 sheets in it.  When I deploy to "real" book it works for 1 or 2 sheets and then suddenly starts selecting crazy numbers of ranges for subsequent sheets so the chart is wrong and unreadable.  This is repeatable and consistent - e.g. for the 3rd sheet it doe sit wrong no matter how many times I run it.

**The weird bit**: when I run the macro through debug, it works flawlessly.  And then when I run it at full speed it works for any sheets that I ran through the debugger.  Once a sheet is "fixed" it seems to work but other sheets don't.

Help?

TL;DR: a tested macro is suddenly selecting too many ranges for some worksheets but not others.  When I watch it for errors, it works.

Comment: You are recommended to shown a minimal reproducible example of your question.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not entirely sure what that means.  All the bits work - it's when I put them into a large workbook that they don't.  What would help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help. Without your existing code there is not much we can do but guess.

Comment: At a guess one of your lines doesn't explicitly specify which worksheet to reference, so Excel uses the current sheet. The classic is inside another reference:  set r = ws.range(range("a1"),range("a1").end(xldown))  is wrong, it should be set r = ws.range(ws.range("a1"),ws.range("a1").end(xldown)